# NVIDIA GTX 1650 not detected on Debian 10

Tags: debian, nvidia, asus, bumblebee, optimus

#Solved
It was hardware problem, my motherboard was broken. Fixed now.

#Problem

I can’t figure out how to install Nvidia driver on my laptop.
(I’m being linux user for only 4-5 days, but I think I try hard enough.)

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:/$ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          paraduxos@ASUSDOGE 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------------ 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: ROG Strix G531GT_G531GT 1.0 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 4.19.0-8-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 1 hour, 42 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2256 (dpkg) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.0.3 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Xfce 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: Xfwm4 
  `Y$$                        WM Theme: Default 
   `Y$$.                      Theme: Xfce [GTK2], Adwaita [GTK3] 
     `$$b.                    Icons: Tango [GTK2], Adwaita [GTK3] 
       `Y$$b.                 Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
          `"Y$b._             Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
              `"""            CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz 
                              GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630 
                              Memory: 1434MiB / 7828MiB
```

I'm using laptop: ASUS ROG STRIX G 531GT (GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, Intel on-board)

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:/$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1a8 (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**First**, my laptop can't find NVIDIA GPU

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:/$ nvidia-detect
No NVIDIA GPU detected.
```

- I also try with lspci (as shown above), lshw (also with `sudo`), no NVIDIA found.

After I do some research (aka google.com)

- using lspci with grep *something* -> still not found
- installing Nvidia-driver -> still not found (and has some problem)
- some said bumblebee need ([linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/nvidia-gpu-not-detected-4175515079/))
- some said it's BIOS problem ([forums.developer.nvidia.com](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-not-detected-ubuntu/108341/6)): I try go to BIOS set up (F2), no NVIDIA as well (I can capture, please tell me if you need.)

I don't know how to configure BIOS so I go with nvidia-driver and bumblebee choice.

From Debian wiki, I found 3 wikis that might be related to my problems:

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers:

> The NVIDIA graphics processing unit (GPU) series/codename of an installed video card can usually be identified using the lspci command.
>
> Note: if this lspci command returns more than one line of output, you
> have an Optimus (hybrid) graphics chipset, and **the instructions on
> this page do not apply to you.** Check the NVIDIA Optimus page instead.

Well, I got 0 output. But I decide to go with Optimus and discontinue this wiki. (I think I'm right, maybe?)

(I actually come back to this later, and install `Version 440.59 (via buster-backports)` and after reboot, nothing happen.)

In [Configuration part](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Configuration) I haven't tried, since it state that

> However, the configuration described below should not be applied to Nvidia Optimus systems;

So I came to the second wiki

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers/Optimus

```
$ lspci | grep 3D (No output)
```

This wiki said that there are 2 ways.

> First: Dynamic Graphics Disabled - xrandr and Display Manager Scripts

- This method require BusID from lspci. so I can't go with this method.

> Second: Dynamic Graphics with Bumblebee

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:/$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

No hybrid GPU??. I'm not quite understand the output so I continue to install Bumblebee.

https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee

Since I'm using Debian 10 (Buster) I following the wiki but found problem.

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:/$ sudo apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus libgl1-nvidia-tesla-glx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-nvidia-tesla-glx
```

I tried google this but none seems answer my question. So I tried

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:/$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus libgl1-nvidia-glx primus-libs:i386 libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
primus-libs:i386 is already the newest version (0~20150328-7).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-nvidia-glx : Depends: libnvidia-glcore (= 418.74-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-nonglvnd (= 418.74-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 418.74-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 nvidia-kernel-418.74
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know what to do next. Please help.

---

**UPDATE:**

- Since `sudo apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus libgl1-nvidia-tesla-glx` return `E: Unable to locate package libgl1-nvidia-tesla-glx` so I remove that and run `sudo apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus`
- I do the same with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus libgl1-nvidia-glx primus-libs:i386`  change to `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus primus-libs:i386`

After I run bumblebee, it returns

```
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:~$ optirun glxgears -info
[ 1097.543100] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 1097.543133] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

---

This is my second attempt after re-install Debian 10

(Live install non-free (XFCE) [Debian non-free](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.3.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/))

This is my `sources.list`

```
# See https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList for more information.
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

# buster-backports
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

I tried switch the comment of backport section (and run `sudo apt update`) but still got same result.

I haven't do anything with my Xorg, .xinit, or anything.

(I also read related question but I think I better ask here.)

- https://superuser.com/questions/1521457/debian-10-on-hp-desktop-with-geforce-gtx-1650-stuck-on-black-screen-and-cursor
- https://superuser.com/questions/1484109/debian-10-hybrid-graphics-how-to-use-nvidia-drivers-instead-of-nouveau

Comment: Hmm ... I thought lspci should show the card, even if the correct driver/kernel module isn't loaded? If so, might that suggest a fault with the hardware?

Comment: That's also one of my thought but I guess not because I just bought this laptop 4-5 months ago, any advice??

Comment: I would try a different distro, e.g. Ubuntu or Mint. You could just do it from a live USB. If you get the same result there with `lspci`, it might suggest hardware issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch to windows 10 and still not detect.
So I turned my laptop to ASUS store.

Turned out, it was hardware problem.
My motherboard was broken.

Now it’s work.

Answer (score 1):

Searching nVidia, it seems version 435.21 is the minimum needed.
Those aren't [debian offered versions of nvidia-driver](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia-driver) packages, but buster-backports give you the opportunity to use 440.59 as of writing. You should add backports in your repositories and [force nvidia-driver from there](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/amd64/nvidia-driver/download).

Greetings.

-edit- didn't read everything !

You tried the backports, but an `apt update` is not enough. You have to signal [APT you want the backported version](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports) of this package.

```
apt -t buster-backports install nvidia-driver
```

Comment: Thank you. I add backport, run command. This is the output > nvidia-driver is already the newest version (440.59-1~bpo10+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 211 not upgraded. (I'm not sure what should I upgrade since it contains unstable Kernel so I didn't run upgrade command). After I reboot, still can't detect NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: In addition, I actually don't care about backport. I just can't install version 418 (sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver). So I go with the backport method. Honestly, this is such a pain, I'm planning to go back to window first to check whether my NVIDIA is working there. And re-build Debian 10 USB installer again. I'm too tired now.

Answer (score 1):

After 1 week of multiple re-installation, I decided to give up.
I uninstall those drivers, go to customize other parts of my laptop change config, edit grub, power management.

And surprisingly, out of nowhere. I run `neofetch`

```bsh
paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:~$ neofetch 
       _,met$$$$$gg.          paraduxos@ASUSDOGE 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------------ 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: ROG Strix G531GT_G531GT 1.0 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 4.19.0-8-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 5 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2404 (dpkg) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.0.3 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         WM: i3 
 `$$b      "-.__              Theme: Adwaita [GTK3] 
  `Y$$                        Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
   `Y$$.                      Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
     `$$b.                    Terminal Font: DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono 12 
       `Y$$b.                 CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz 
          `"Y$b._             GPU: NVIDIA NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 
              `"""            GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630 
                              Memory: 983MiB / 7828MiB 




paraduxos@ASUSDOGE:~$ nvidia-detect 
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1f91] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
Your card is supported by the default drivers.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```

I'm not sure what happen. But the different from then and now are:

```bsh
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
# This line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux quiet splash"
# quit and run
sudo update-grub
# then reboot
```

- I switch to polybar instead of i3-bar
- I install thermald, tlp tlp-rdw, powertop(uninstall)
- Some config that I'm not sure which one.

I think it's because of `GRUB` but I don't want to prove it. (haha)
For those who found this, you could try add `acpi_osi=Linux` in your `GRUB`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me based on [user4089's answer above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/576724/47775) for a GTX 1650s on `debian buster` or super was

add to `/etc/apt/sources.list/

```
# Backports repository
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free # available     after buster release
```

then

```
sudo  apt-get -t buster-backports install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

reboot and working!